# Python Tkinter call default event handler

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI with an entry box and buttons. When I press "q" the close button shall be focused, except when the entry has the focus. Focusing the button when pressing "q" works, but when I want to insert a "q" in the entry it looses it's focus so that I can't continue inserting text into the entry box.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self):
                tk.Tk.__init__(self)

                self.e = tk.Entry(self)
                self.e.pack()

                f = tk.Frame(self)
                f.pack()

                self.btn_save = tk.Button(f, text="save", command=lambda: print("save"))
                self.btn_save.pack(side='left')

                self.btn_close = tk.Button(f, text="close", command=self.destroy)
                self.btn_close.pack(side='left')

                self.bind('<w>', lambda e: self.btn_save.focus_set())
                self.bind('<q>', lambda e: self.btn_close.focus_set())

                self.e.focus_set()

w = Window()
w.mainloop()
```

I know that for a custom event handler I can avoid further event handlers to be called by returning `'break'`. But how can I call the event handler of the `Entry`?
In the following code pressing "q" does not focus the close button anymore when the entry is selected, but I can insert no text anymore at all.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self):
                tk.Tk.__init__(self)

                self.e = tk.Entry(self)
                self.e.pack()

                f = tk.Frame(self)
                f.pack()

                self.btn_save = tk.Button(f, text="save", command=lambda: print("save"))
                self.btn_save.pack(side='left')

                self.btn_close = tk.Button(f, text="close", command=self.destroy)
                self.btn_close.pack(side='left')

                self.bind('<w>', lambda e: self.btn_save.focus_set())
                self.bind('<q>', lambda e: self.btn_close.focus_set())

                self.e.bind('<Key>', self.on_key_press)
                self.e.focus_set()

        def on_key_press(self, event):
                # How can I call the default event handler here
                # which takes care of inserting and removing characters, moving the cursor and everything?
                return 'break'

w = Window()
w.mainloop()
```

(Btw when invoking the close button via the keyboard, the window closes as expected but the keyboard is ignored afterwards until I click on another window. I am using i3 version 4.8 and Python 3.4.2.)

Comment: if you do `return 'break'` it will not call the default handler. If you remove the `return 'break'` it will be called. Is that not what you want?

Comment: @ritlew yes, but then it would also call the other event handlers and if I try to enter a "q" into the entry box the entry box would loose focus, which is not what I want. I only want the event handler of the Entry to be executed, not those bound to the root window.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround which does not seem very elegant, though.
Especially if you have several entry boxes this does not seem like a good way to go.

Inside of the event handlers focusing the buttons, check which widget has the focus and do nothing if it is the entry box:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Window(tk.Tk):

        def __init__(self):
                tk.Tk.__init__(self)

                self.e = tk.Entry(self)
                self.e.pack()

                self.frame_buttons = tk.Frame(self)
                self.frame_buttons.pack()

                self.btn_save = tk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="save", command=lambda:              print("save"))
                self.btn_save.pack(side='left')

                self.btn_close = tk.Button(self.frame_buttons, text="close", command=self.destroy)
                self.btn_close.pack(side='left')

                self.bind('<w>', lambda e: None if self.focus_get() == self.e else self.btn_save.       focus_set())
                self.bind('<q>', lambda e: None if self.focus_get() == self.e else self.btn_close.      focus_set())

                self.e.focus_set()

w = Window()
w.mainloop()
```

I would appreciate it if someone would find a better solution.

---

Regarding the problem that the keyboard is ignored after invoking the close button via the keyboard it seems to help to unpack the buttons frame and update the window before destroying it:

```
        def destroy(self):
                self.frame_buttons.pack_forget()
                self.update()
                tk.Tk.destroy(self)
```